# foreach() SQL query get just unique results

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I have a row `performanta_cpu` in my table `modele`  and that row contain diferent numeric  cpu's frecv. ex: `800, 1200, 1500,` etc and i want to foreach all frecv. but if 4 devices have same cpu speed, shows me 4th times same frecv.

Is there posible to get just once a frecv in `html <select>` ex: `800`, `1000`, `1200`, `1400`, etc ?

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu DESC";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $linie)
        {

    print '<option value="'.$linie["performanta_cpu"].'">'.$linie["performanta_cpu"].'</option>'; }?>
```

and this is what i get:

```
           <option value="800">800</option>
           <option value="800">800</option>
           <option value="2000">2000</option>
           <option value="2000">2000</option>
           <option value="1600">1600</option>
           <option value="1500">1500</option>
           <option value="1500">1500</option>
           <option value="1500">1500</option>
           <option value="1400">1400</option>
           <option value="1000">1000</option>
           <option value="1000">1000</option>
           <option value="1000">1000</option>
           <option value=""></option>
```

The correct will be like this:

```
           <option value="1600">1600</option>
           <option value="1500">1500</option>
           <option value="1400">1400</option>
           <option value="1300">1300</option>
           <option value="1200">1200</option>
           <option value="1100">1100</option>
           and so...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `SELECT DISTINCT(performanta_cpu) FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY CAST(performanta_cpu AS UNSIGNED) DESC`

Comment: I get wrong first result like: 800, 1600, 1500, 1400, etc. First must be 1600 because is te biggest. Any Ideeas?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using an integer field. Answer updated.

Comment: @Domuta Marcel 800, 1600, 1500 is sorted as string data, not integer, so 8 is a larger characeter than 1 and hence is first in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Change the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT(performanta_cpu) FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu DESC
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a keyword, not a function

Comment: gerardo, is working but not as well, first is 800, 2000, 1600, 1500, 1400, etc. Why is there 800?

Comment: 800 is only one device in database with him, is unique, but in future it will be populated...

Answer (score 1):

If you will add DISTINCT, its must work.

> SELECT **DISTINCT**(performanta_cpu) FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY
>   performanta_cpu

Comment: I get wrong first result like: 800, 1600, 1500, 1400, etc. First must be 1600 because is te biggest. Ideeas?

Comment: Please, explain the meaning of DISTINCT option.

Comment: @Domuta Marcel 800, 1600, 1500 is sorted as string data, not integer, so 8 is a larger characeter than 1 and hence is first in the list.  See Rob's answer.

Comment: @asclepix In context: If the query fetches '800' multiple times, DISTINCT only gives 1 instance of '800' back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY performanta_cpu DESC";
$cpu = array();
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $linie)
    $cpu[] = $linie["performanta_cpu"];

$cpu = array_unique($cpu);

foreach($cpu as $val)
    print '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>'; }?>
```